# How to add a specific number to an index in python?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a function in python that checks if the value of `listy_poo[0]` is a certain value. If it is, I need to skip index `1` and get the value of index `2`.

My code:

```
def find():
    i = 0
    for e in listy_poo:
        if listy_poo[i] == 'value':
            print(listy_poo[i+2])
            i += 1
```

Clearly wrong, but is there something in python that accomplishes what I'm attempting?

UPDATE:
I thought the problem was the syntax of `listy_poo[i+2]` but looking over the history has shown that I actually didn't save my change from when I attempted `listy_poo[i]+2`, which is wrong. Thanks for your help anyway, folks.

Comment: you want to do your same logic for `1st` element as well (The logic that you perform for element with index 2 onwards)?

Comment: No, I need to skip the first element. The list is formatted in a way that guarantees that if 'value' is found, then exactly two elements over is another value which I need to extract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is close to working. If you change it to

```
def find(listy_poo, value_str):
    for i, e in enumerate(listy_poo):
        if e == value_str and i+2 < len(listy_poo):
            print(listy_poo[i+2])
```

The enumerate() function returns a tuple of the index of the given item in the list, and the item itself. I also added a check (`i+2 < len(listy_poo)`) to make sure you don't get an IndexError.

Looking at your description, I'm not positive this is doing what you want.

If you ran `find(['a','b','c','d'],'b')` then the function would print out `d`. That is, whenever it finds a match for the value, it moves over two spots in the list, and prints that value. Is that what you are going for?

Comment: Even though the bug I caught in my code fixed the basic functionality, this is a better solution for what I need.  Thanks!